# How to use if and else statements to achieve Age Classifier program

Tags: python, if-statement, classification

I have an assignment in my Python class. It says:

> Write a program that asks the user to enter a person's age. The
>   program should display a message indicating whether the person is an
>   infant, child, teenager, or adult. Here are the following guidelines:
>
> - If the person is 1 year old or less, he or she is an infant.
> - If the person is older than 1 year, but younger than 13 years, he or she is a child.
> - If the person is at least 13 years old, but less than 20 years old, he or she is a teenager.
> - If the person is at least 20 years old, he or she is an adult.

Here's what I have so far. I'm assuming you use `if` and `else` statements.

```
age = int(input('Please enter a persons age.'))
if age <= 1: print('The person is an infant.')
else: print('The person is not an infant.')
if age > 1 and age > 13: print('The person is a child.')
else: print ('The person is not an infant.')
if age <= 13 and age > 20: print('The person is a teenager.')
else: print ('The person is not a teenager.')
if age >=20: print ('The person is an adult.')
```

Problem is, when I enter a number, example, the number '4', the program runs as so:

```
The person is not an infant.
The person is not an infant.
The person is not a teenager.
```

That is all it reads to me. So how do I fix this? Because I thought I was on the right track.

Comment: `age > 1 and age > 13` - what does that cover? How about `age <= 13 and age > 20` (*hint: nothing*)? You would probably find this **much easier** if you used a consistent comparison order, as well as newlines and indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the use of chained if statements using the terms if, elif and else:

```
# ask user to input age
age = int(input('Please enter a persons age.'))

# if a person is 1 or younger
if age <= 1:
    print 'The person is an infant.'
# if a person is older than 1 but younger than 13
elif age > 1 and age < 13:
    print 'The person is a child.'
# if a person is at least 13, but less than 20
elif age >= 13 and age < 20:
    print 'The person is a teenager.'
else if age >= 20:
    print 'The person is an adult.'
```

It seems like there are two points you should be learning from this exercise. The first is how to chain together if/elif/else statements. It's more efficient to do this than to evaluate each clause separately. As you can see above, you do this by using 'if' on the first statement, 'elif' on the following statements, an 'else' on the final statement.

This is also useful for error checking. You could do something as follows:

```
# ask user to input age
age = int(input('Please enter a persons age.'))

# if a person is 1 or younger
if age <= 1:
    print 'The person is an infant.'
# if a person is older than 1 but younger than 13
elif age > 1 and age < 13:
    print 'The person is a child.'
# if a person is at least 13, but less than 20
elif age >= 13 and age < 20:
    print 'The person is a teenager.'
elif if age >= 20:
    print 'The person is an adult.'
else:
    print 'Check that your input is an integer and try again.'
```

The second is the difference between < > and <= >=. Notice the assignment classifies someone as an infant if they are under the age of 1. This does not include the age of one, only people who have not yet reached the age of 1, therefore you would use '< 1' to get everything up to 364 days old.

This is different than when it classifies someone who is 'at least' 13 as a teenager. This means they can be 13 or above, therefore you would use '>= 13'.

Comment: Thank you, I actually just figured it out right before you posted this. It looks exactly like yours except I forgot to add the last else statement. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are stuck in a loop you need to tell the program what to say, eg.
if age <=1 :
Print ("you are a infant")
Else:
    Print ("you are a child")

Answer (score 0):

```
age = int(input('Please enter a persons age.'))

# if a person is 1 or younger
if age <= 1:
    print ("The person is an infant")
# if a person is older than 1 but younger or same as 13
elif age > 1 and age <= 13:
    print ("The person is a child")
# if a person is at least 13, but less than 20
elif age >= 13 and age < 20:
    print ("The person is a teenager")
elif  age >= 20:
    print ("The person is an adult")
else:
    print ("wrong age")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
from datetime import date

todayDate = date.today();

DOB = input("Please enter your Date of Birth: ");
currentYear = todayDate.year;

age = (int(currentYear) - int(DOB));
print(f'Your current age is: {age}');

print ("\n")
if age <= 5:
    print("You are a baby.")
elif age >= 5 and age < 13:
    print("You are a toddler")
elif age >= 13 and age < 18:
    print("You are an teenager")
elif age >= 18 and age < 60:
    print("You are an adult.")    
elif age >= 60:
    print("You are a senior Citizen")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Write if-elif-else chain to detrmine a person's stage of life.

```
    # Ask for input
    age = int(input('Person age: '))
    
    # if the person is less then 2 year old
    if age <= 2:
        print('The person is Baby.')
    # if the person is least 2 years old but less then 4 
    elif age >= 2 and age <= 4:
        print('The person is Infant.')
    # if the person is at least 4 years old but less then 13
    elif age >= 4 and age <= 13:
        print('The person is Kid.') 
    # if the person is at least 13 years old but less then 20
    elif age >= 13 and age <= 20:
        print('The person is Teenager.') 
    # if the person is at least 20 years old but less then 65
    elif age >= 20 and age <= 65:
        print('The person is Adult.') 
    # if the person age 65 or older
    else:
        if age >= 65:
            print('The person is an Elder.')
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```py
age = int(input("Please enter your age: "))


if age >= 18:
    print("You are an adult.")
elif age >= 13 and age <= 17:
    print("You are a teenager.")
else:
    print("You are a child.")
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

```
age = int(input('Please enter a persons age.'))

# if a person is 1 or younger
if age <= 1:
    print ("The person is an infant")
# if a person is older than 1 but younger or same as 13
elif age > 1 and age <= 13:
    print ("The person is a child")
# if a person is at least 13, but less than 20
elif age >= 13 and age < 20:
    print ("The person is a teenager")
elif  age >= 20:
    print ("The person is an adult")
else:
    print ("wrong age")
```

Comment: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Answer (score -1):

i hope this will solve your problem

```
print "Enter Age"
age = input()
if age<1:
  print "he or she is an infant."
elif age>=1 and age<13:
  print "he or she is a child"
elif age>=13 and age<20:
  print "He or she is an adult"
elif age>=20:
  print "he or she is an adult"
else:
  print "adult"
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -1):

```py
for i in range(5):
    age = int(input('Please enter a persons age.'))
    if age <= 1:                  
        print(f'The person is an infant.')

    elif age > 1 and age < 13:
        print('The person is a child.')

    elif age >= 13 and age < 20:
        print('The person is a teenager.')

    elif age >= 20:
        print('The person is an adult.')

    else:
        print("wrong age")
```

Comment: for i in range(5):
    age = int(input('Please enter a persons age.'))
    if age <= 1:                  
        print(f'The person is an infant.')

    elif age > 1 and age < 13:   
        print('The person is a child.')

    elif age >= 13 and age < 20:  
        print('The person is a teenager.')

    elif age >= 20:
        print('The person is an adult.')

    else:
        print("wrong age")

Comment: please add some explanation what you changed/added